# How to use commands or multiline values for package options/parameters?

Tags: package-options

I would like to know if there's a way to use a command (including custom commands created with `\newcommand`) as parameter/option values). I would like to do something like this

```
\usepackage[someoption=\somecommand]{somepackage}
\usepackage[supporters={First line\\ Second Line}]{someotherpackage}
```

Comment: Not unless you are altering the package itself and adding your options.

Comment: Also note that package options are fully expanded, which makes them sort of impossible to use for anything like this. (Not so with keyval options, though.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: The original question has been edited into an entirely different one. This is not allowed! The editor should ask their own question. The initial question was about passing option values via `\documentclass`, not via `\usepackage`.

Answer (score 5):

If you load the `xkvltxp` (or `kvoptions-patch` or `catoptions`) package before `\documentclass`, you will be fine: you can pass commands as values of options. To load a package before `\documentclass`, you should of course use `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage`.

Answer (score 1):

Two options

1. You can check to see if a csname is defined using `\ifdef` in the package, so that defining `\csname` as a macro before invoking `\usepackage` can be checked.  This isn't exactly what you asked, but it should, I guess, do what you want;
2. You can pass the name of a command as a string without the backslash (say, to `\input`) in the options, and then bind the command using `\edef\inputcs{\def\passname#1{\csname#1\endcsname}\expandafter\passname\input}`.